# Difference Between B330, B330A and B330B?

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, schottky

What is the difference between B330, B330A, and B330B?

I read the datasheets but I couldn't notice the difference.

I want to use it as a freewheeling diode for a DC-DC converter with 12V input, 5V/4A output.

For the selection of the Schottky diode  \$I_F\$  should be greater than 1.66A and the power dissipation equal to \$\mathrm{P_D=1.66A \cdot 0.5(V_{dropout})=880 mW}\$.

I didn't find the power rating for B330B (I intend to use it), B330A that why I am asking for the differences.

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Comment: Lose the capitals, and link the datasheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all the same* diode, just in different package.

- B330 in SMC
- B330**A** in SM**A**
- B330**B** in SM**B**
- B330**C** in SM**C**

* The only difference I've noticed so far (in Diodes Inc's datasheets) is a lower peak forward surge current (I_FSM) of 80A for the B330**A,B** and B330**C** compared to the 100A rating of the B330 *(nothing)*.

---

*I wonder why there is a difference in the Diodes Inc. datasheets between the spec for the B330 and B330C. I would have thought this spec difference would probably arise of the perhaps inferior thermals of the SMA/SMB packages, but why's the B330C's spec any different from the B330? Note, the B330B and B330C use the same datasheet... An error perhaps?*

*Turns out Diodes Inc. datasheets I've looked at do indeed mention 80A for the B330C, but another company, MDD, seems to say this too is good for 100A IFSM. Same method too! And they say it's the case for the B330B from them too... Same about the B330A actually. The I_FSM difference is likely a red herring. It's the same diode.*